# Securing a Web Service with X.509 certificate. Which is best?

Tags: .net, wcf, security, x509

I am quite a novice at this so please bear with me. I have a web service developed with WCF that will be consumed by non-.NET client. Currently I am looking to secure it. I have come to the conclusion the best option is to use WsHttpBinding and an X509 certificate. However, when it comes to obtaining a certificate I am a bit lost. Is a X509 the same as an SSL certificate? What it the best certificate I should be looking to get for such a scenario?

Comment: Yes, [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) specifies the format for a number of things that are important for PKI. What are your security requirements? Is this a web service on the public internet? If so, you should probably go with a certificate signed by a trusted [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

Comment: Will be on the public internet, and in fact it's a payment gateway so security is a big concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya hope these 2 will help you; I used it in my previous project; (Yes)

http://www.phildev.net/ssl/ssl_talk_uuasc.pdf

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/what-is-the-difference-between-an-x-509-client-certificate-and-a-normal-ssl-ce

http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x595.html

Chrees!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You are close. SSL uses x.509 certificates. x.509 is the certificate standard. It's what ensures Firefox can understand a certificate presented by IIS. But x.509 certificates are used for a lot more than just SSL. It's also used for signing documents, signing applications, secure key exchange, and others.

SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is a protocol for secure communication that uses these certificates for, among other things, proving the identity of your service. When a client connects to your service, it presents an x.509 certificate, bound to your domain, that is signed by a certificate authority (CA) the client also trusts. Most often it's bought from a third party CA, like Verisgn, GoDaddy, Entrust, or countless others.

Edited based on new comments:

If it's public facing, you'll definitely want to purchase the certificate from a third party CA. Verisign is the biggest, but they are also the most expensive.

It's also important to note, SSL and certificates don't really make a web service "secure". It just protects the client communication, and prevents attackers from impersonating you. There might be other security concerns as well.

Comment: I have no control over the clients. In fact, I need to produce a secure API that will later be resold to various clients that are external parties. So one question then. If I purchase an SSL certificate, can I use it for authentication as a X509 AND to ensure a secure transmission channel over https? Or do I need 2 different certificates in this case?

Comment: Maybe I complicated the answer a bit. What do you mean, use it for authentication. SSL will provide authentication of the web service. It ensures when someone connects to your API, it's really your servers. If you're talking about authentication in this sense, then one certificate is all you need.

Comment: To clarify - SSL, when properly configured, provides both authentication and confidentiality. Does WCF use the certificate for something above-and-beyond SSL? (it sounds like it's just for doing an HTTPS connection, but I don't know WCF that well)

Comment: I thought using an X509 I could ensure mutual authentication, meaning I can be sure the client is who he says he is, because he is presenting the certificate, and he can be sure he is connecting to the right server. Am I misunderstanding this? Sorry, like I said I am a big time novice when it comes to security.

Comment: You're right, you can do mutual authentication with SSL. Client authentication tends to be a lot less common. In this case, your service needs a certificate, and each client needs it's own unique client certificate (which is different than a standard SSL cert for a web service). You could either issue these yourself, or also buy them from a 3rd party.

Comment: So in this case it's not ONE standard SSL certificate which I purchase install, and later provide to each client. I would just generate my own for each client. Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to purchase one standard SSL certificate for yourself. You then either need to (easy) tell each client to buy a client certificate or generate it themselves, or (hard) set up a CA and generate them yourself. Honestly, this is decently complex architecture. I'd recommend spending a few minutes on the Verisign site reading their introductions and guides. All this will make more sense.